# Electron affinity from first principles

Tags: special-relativity, simulations, dirac-equation, hydrogen, ionization-energy

How accurately has the [electron affinity of Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_anion) been simulated (compared to its measured value of  0.754195 eV)?

It seems like this could be a good check on whether two electrons have any ability to jointly occupy a single state (the current theory, where electrons are [fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion), says that this ability is exactly zero).

Comment: One place to start is J. Chem. Phys. 119, 3130 (2003); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1589735

Comment: @JonCuster That sounds like an answer.  If I understand correctly, they get 0.754246 eV without even including relativistic or QED effects...really?